# NSIS installs sections even after I have removed them

Tags: nsis

I have built an installer, which consists of 5 sections/components. I have created a pre-function before the components page to check which components are installed, only the components that are not currently installed should be shown on the components page.

```
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE selectSections
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS

...
Function selectSections
            ; remove sections which are already installed
            ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "${REG_INSTALL}" "SEC_EXTRACTOR"
            IfErrors +2
            !insertmacro RemoveSection ${SEC_EXTRACTOR}
            !insertmacro SelectSection ${SEC_EXTRACTOR}
            ; so on for all components
FunctionEnd
```

So I install all the components first, and then run the installer again. This time I do not see any components on the components page. But when I press install on that page, all the sections are still executed. Can anyone help ?

(I have pressed the install button from a components page, that does not list any components. but I see those sections being installed in the details pane.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use relative jumps to skip macros because a macro can be more that one instruction. Use `IfErrors label` or `${If} ${Errors}` from LogicLib.nsh.